# Adding new nested entry to JSONobject using Ramda

Tags: javascript, angular, ramda.js

Have an initial empty object to which we are supposed to add json data. Using lodash was able to add it as follows.

```
const _ = require('lodash');
data = {};
_.set(data, 'client.firstName', incomingData.firstName ? incomingData.firstName : '');
_.set(data, 'client.lastName', incomingData.lastName ? incomingData.lastName : '');
_.set(data, 'client.middleInitial', incomingData.middleInitial ? incomingData.middleInitial : '');
_.set(data, 'maidenName', incomingData.maidenName ? incomingData.maidenName : '');
...
```

Now am supposed to do the same implementation using **rambda**.
Tried out by referring ramda docs but couldn't reach to an exact solution such that the output is recieved like this :

```
{
"client": 
  {
   "firstName":"Pete",
   "lastName":"Cathy",
   "middleInitial":"M"
  },
"maidenName":"catty"
...
...
}
```

Please suggest me the right implementation to achieve the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My first suggestion is that you don't assume that something in lodash will be in Ramda or vice versa.  They are independent libraries with different goals and different features.  That they overlap so much is due to the fact that lodash (via Underscore) and Ramda (directly) take inspiration from many of the functional languages out there.  But they take that inspiration in different directions.

In Ramda (disclaimer: I'm one of its authors) we would avoid code like that snippet.    But we *could* get fairly close:

### Most direct conversion

We could write something relatively close:

```js
const _set = (o, ps, v) => assocPath (split ('.') (ps), v, o)

const incomingData = {firstName: 'Wilma', lastName: 'Flintstone', maidenName: 'Slaghoople'}

let data = {}

data = _set (data, 'client.firstName', incomingData.firstName ? incomingData.firstName : '');
data = _set (data, 'client.lastName', incomingData.lastName ? incomingData.lastName : '');
data = _set (data, 'client.middleInitial', incomingData.middleInitial ? incomingData.middleInitial : '');
data = _set (data, 'maidenName', incomingData.maidenName ? incomingData.maidenName : '');

console .log (data)
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.27.1/ramda.min.js"></script>
<script> const {assocPath, split} = R </script>
```

The big difference is in the continual reassignment of `data`.  Ramda does not mutate input data; that is one of its core principles.  So we would have to use our new `_set` function to return a new object and then reset `data` to the result.

### Not the Ramda way

But Ramda users would be quite unlikely to write code like that.  The continual mutation of `data` is an anathema.  Moreover it's quite repetitive.  We would like to wrap those repeated imperative blocks into something more declarative.

### Using a `path`-configuration

A first possibility is to use a configuration like

```js
[
  ['client.firstName', 'firstName', ''],
  ['client.lastName',  'lastName', ''],
  ['client.middleInitial', 'middleInitial', ''],
  ['client.maidenName', 'maidenName', ''],
]
```

to drive our code.  We could fold these entries into a single object in a simple enough manner in Ramda:

```js
const transform = curry ((config, incoming) => reduce (
  (obj, [to, from, dflt]) =>
    assocPath (split ('.') (to), defaultTo (dflt, path (split ('.') (from), incoming)), obj), 
  {}, config
))

const config = [
  ['client.firstName', 'firstName', ''],
  ['client.lastName',  'lastName', ''],
  ['client.middleInitial', 'middleInitial', ''],
  ['maidenName', 'maidenName', ''],
]

const incomingData = {firstName: 'Wilma', lastName: 'Flintstone', maidenName: 'Slaghoople'}

console .log (transform (config) (incomingData))
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.27.1/ramda.min.js"></script>
<script> const {curry, reduce, assocPath, split, defaultTo, path} = R </script>
```

Here we use the dot-separated paths in the input configuration to detail where our data is coming from and going to, and we supply simple defaults for missing values.

This style is quite useful if you are already getting data in this dot-separated path format.  But that format is not particularly natural for Ramda, which uses arrays of Strings and Integers for its paths.  So, while I'll leave it as a simplification exercise, we might prefer working with a configuration like this:

```js
const config = [
  [['client', 'firstName'], ['firstName'], ''],
  [['client', 'lastName'],  ['lastName'], ''],
  [['client', 'middleInitial'], ['middleInitial'], ''],
  [['maidenName'], ['maidenName'], ''],
]
```

### Built into Ramda

But if you're writing from scratch, and not starting with those dot-separated paths, Ramda has a built-in function that is still more declarative and is very much designed for such jobs: the function `applySpec`, which takes an input object and builds a new one by applying a structured configuration object whose leaves are functions from the input data.  (I see that Ori Drori has an answer with nearly identical code.  I think it's worth repeating here, if nothing else to show that this is the most likely Ramda answer to the problem.)

Using `applySpec` is simple enough:

```js
const transform = applySpec ({
  client: {
    firstName: propOr ('', 'firstName'),
    lastName: propOr ('', 'lastName'),
    middleInitial: propOr ('', 'middleInitial')
  },
  maidenName: propOr ('', 'maidenName')
}) 

const incomingData = {firstName: 'Wilma', lastName: 'Flintstone', maidenName: 'Slaghoople'}

console .log (transform (incomingData))
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.27.1/ramda.min.js"></script>
<script> const {applySpec, propOr} = R </script>
```

This is nicely declarative; our configuration object is structured like the output we want to receive.  The functions on its leaves using `propOr` simply describe where to fetch the data from our input and what to do if its missing.  (If our input is nested, we might use `pathOr` instead.)

### Which technique?

The choice between these two techniques would depend on whether the list of paths, say `'client.firstName'` is known ahead of time or is data supplied to you.  The snippet supplied suggests the former, and with that, I would suggest the `applySpec` solution.  But if that's not really the case, and those paths might be supplied as data, then the `reduce`-based one is likely best.

Answer (score 2):

With Ramda you can use `R.applySpec` to create a new object from another object by supplying a spec that includes function that generate each property. In your case, use `R.propOr` to take the data from the original object, and supply an empty string as fallback:

```js
const { applySpec, propOr } = R;

const getData = applySpec({
  client: {
   firstName: propOr('', 'firstName'),
   lastName: propOr('', 'lastName'),
   middleInitial: propOr('', 'middleInitial')
  },
  maidenName: propOr('', 'maidenName')
});

const incomingData = {
  firstName: 'Pete',
  lastName: 'Cathy',
  maidenName: 'Catty',
};

const data = getData(incomingData);

console.log(data);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.27.1/ramda.min.js" integrity="sha512-rZHvUXcc1zWKsxm7rJ8lVQuIr1oOmm7cShlvpV0gWf0RvbcJN6x96al/Rp2L2BI4a4ZkT2/YfVe/8YvB2UHzQw==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
```

*Rambda* works the same way, but at least the UMD seems to have a bug. If `R.propOr` is supplied to all properties the function returns an empty object. If you encounter the bug wrap one of `propOr` calls with a function as a hack to make it work.

```js
const { applySpec, propOr } = R;

const getData = applySpec({
  client: {
   firstName: x => propOr('', 'firstName', x), // <- stupid hack
   lastName: propOr('', 'lastName'),
   middleInitial: propOr('', 'middleInitial')
  },
  maidenName: propOr('', 'maidenName')
});

const incomingData = {
  firstName: 'Pete',
  lastName: 'Cathy',
  maidenName: 'Catty',
};

const data = getData(incomingData);

console.log(data);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rambda/6.9.0/rambda.umd.js" integrity="sha512-1npVFfj/soXclDC0ts7zenNSKArClG4bNYSpOLuE5ojVI7mXLLdkoRvXGejgOS1p/zORDKajYMxXw/Ia6vNulQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
```

Comment: Good one, pretty straight forward for flat scenarios.